# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: When validating XML against a XSD

Tags: c#, xml, exception, random, xsd

I have a program written in C# that validates a XML files against a schema.

Sometimes when I call `xmlSchemaCollection.Add(null, schemaFileName)` where  `xmlSchemaCollection` is a `XmlSchemaCollection` and `schemaFileName` is the uri to the schema file I get:

> “System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path”.

The file with the schema exists on a local disc and everyone has read permission on it. This happens randomly about one time out of 100.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: what uri you have in schemaFileName?

Comment: schemaFileName == "C:\\BrackeGis\\xmlschema\\BGO-Info-1_2.xsd"

Answer (score 0):

Your schema references another schema and the parser is trying to open it from an (unexisting) file location. Can you post the first lines of the xsd?

Comment: The schema looks like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="xxxxx">
  ...
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Answer (score 0):

Write like this

```
sc.Add(null, "DataSet1.xsd");
```

Add DataSet1.xsd to your project and set property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always". (Right click DataSet1.xsd and select properties to set the property)

Hope this will help you...

**Edited**

I have created the same path and same schema name in my system that you have given and I am able to execute following code without any exception:

```
try
        {
            XmlSchemaCollection sc = new XmlSchemaCollection();
            sc.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(sc_ValidationEventHandler);

            var schemaFileName = "C:\\BrackeGis\\xmlschema\\BGO-Info-1_2.xsd";

            sc.Add(null, schemaFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

There must be some mistake in path that you have created . . .

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my program that is responsible for the XSD.

Comment: It works on my computer as well. But on our server where the program is running, the problem occurs sometimes, but far from always.